# Is there no support for Complex Ruby markup (HTML) in browsers?

Tags: html, browser, markup

I tried an example like the one found on [w3.org/TR/ruby](http://www.w3.org/TR/ruby/#complex)
but neither Firefox nor Chromium managed to render it correctly (i.e. at least somewhat similar to [Fig1.10 on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/ruby/#fig1.10)).

So is there support for **complex** Ruby markup in any browser? I guess one could come up with CSS handling the situation but simple ruby markup seems to be (somewhat) widely supported without any extra work. Is anyone working on this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems Ruby isn't supported well, [watch this](http://caniuse.com/#search=ruby)

Comment: My Firefox 42 does not render it in a useful way, but it is listed as "Supported". Seems no browser does actually support it all then.

Comment: True, theres a tab below "known issues"

Quote: IE and Firefox do not appear to have support for nested ruby structures see [testcase](http://jsfiddle.net/tabletguy/49412u7r/)

Comment: That seems to be yet another thing. The testcase you linked uses nested simple ruby (which seems to work in Chromium!), but there is also **complex** ruby which uses additional tags (rbc, rtc). I think the testcase should use rb tags around the chinese characters but that does not produce a better result in FF either.